# Laravel DB::raw

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.6

```
   Trip::select('trips.id','trips.date_trip',
        DB::raw('(select count(region_id) as count from trip_regions where trip_id=trips.id) as count')
    )->where('count',10)->get();
```

ERRor

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in 
'where clause' (SQL: select `trips`.`id`, `trips`.`date_trip`, (select 
count(region_id) as sum from trip_regions where trip_id=trips.id) as 
count from `trips` where `count` = 10)
```

i have query line want to DB::raw. Can you help me??? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `having` clause

```
Trip::select('trips.id','trips.date_trip',
    DB::raw('(select count(region_id) as count from trip_regions where trip_id=trips.id) as count')
)->having('count', '=',10)->get();
```

You cannot apply `where` clause on custom aliases, `where` is applicable for only columns that exists in your table(s). To filter out result of expressions/aggregate result set you will need `having` clause

Comment: ->whereBetween('count',[$date, $date_today])

Comment: if it is where between

Comment: @UlasoftKoinotUz I don't get your point to check a number is between a date range ? You could also use `havingRaw()` for your raw query/statement , Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Comment: ->whereBetween('count',[$min, $max])

Comment: @UlasoftKoinotUz you could write your expression using `havingRaw` like `havingRaw('count between '. $min.' and '. $max)`